# Set background of JPanel object a second time

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

To help learn more about `EventListeners` in Java, I've created a simple program that consists of one `JFrame` and two `JPanels` and all it's supposed to do is toggle a secondary color on the `Jpanel` as it is clicked on.

My code changes each JPanel to the new secondary color when it gets clicked but when it gets clicked a second time it does revert back to the original color. What do I need to change to get it to work correctly? I've tried re-writing the code multiple times so I must be missing some concept of how EventListeners or JPanels work.

```
package com.spencerlarry;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class View extends JFrame{

    public static final int OFF = 1;
    public static final int ON = 1;

    public static final String DARKGRAY = "#696969";
    public static final String CYAN = "#00FFFF";

    Space top;
    Space bottom;

    public View(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Window Test");
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setMinimumSize(getSize());

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        add(new Space());
        add(new Space());

    }

    public class Space extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

        private String color;

        public Space(){
            setBackground(Color.decode(DARKGRAY));
            addMouseListener(this);
        }

        public String getColor(String c){
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(){
            if(color == CYAN){
                setBackground(Color.decode(DARKGRAY));
            }
            else{
                setBackground(Color.decode(CYAN));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            this.setColor();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [don't compare `Strings` with `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Your if statement should be:

```
if(color.equals(CYAN))
```

But this is going to throw a null pointer exception the first time, since you aren't initializing the value of `color`.

You aren't actually setting or changing the value of the `color` variable, so when you check

```
if(color == CYAN)
```

it always evaluates to false, meaning you are always calling

```
setBackground(Color.decode(CYAN));
```

when you click, no matter what.

In your `Space` constructor, you should initialize `color` to `DARKGRAY` (to avoid the null pointer exception), and then change `setColour()` to something like this:

```
public void setColor(){
    if(color.equals(CYAN)){
        setBackground(Color.decode(DARKGRAY));
        color = DARKGRAY;
    }
    else{
        setBackground(Color.decode(CYAN));
        color = CYAN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer given by @gla3dr, why decode the color string every time? Just define:

```
public static final Color MY_DARKGRAY = new Color("#696969");
// there is already a standard Color.CYAN, so don't re-define it
```

then set the color in your constructor, and

```
public void setColor(){
    if( color == Color.CYAN )){
        setBackground( MY_DARKGRAY );
        color = MY_DARKGRAY;
    }
    else{
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        color = Color.CYAN;
    }
}
```

Comment: @spencerlarry Note, the `color` variable will have to be changed from a `String` to a `Color` if you do this.